# Create Proxy for prototype method

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-proxy

I am fumbling for a way to avoid creating a new Proxy for each new object instance. I have 1 prototype, and I want to use just 1 Proxy. That's the goal. If I use a Proxy per instance, I could have thousands and thousands of Proxy objects which hurts performance a lot.

Ultimately what I am doing is setting properties on a prototype method, like this:

```
const v = {
  foo: function () {
    assert.notEqual(this, v);
  }
};

v.foo.bar = function(){
   // I need `this` to be a certain value here
};

v.foo.zam = function(){
   // I need `this` to be a certain value here
};
```

but I need those properties to still have the same context (`this` value), as the prototype method itself would.

```
const assert = require('assert');

const v = {
  foo: function () {
    assert.notEqual(this, v);
  }
};

new Proxy(v.foo, {
  get: function(target, prop){
     console.log(this); // I am looking to get access to `x` here
  }
});


const x = Object.create(v);

x.foo();
const z = x.foo.bar; // I would have guessed this would have fired the Proxy `get` method.
```

I am trying to do some black magic, where I can access the `this` value of the v prototype methods from the Proxy. In this case, that would mean accessing the value of `x` from the Proxy. Is this possible somehow? Also, I can't figure out why the get method of the Proxy is not called when I read the `bar` property from  `x.foo`, as in `x.foo.bar`.

this Github gist I just created is a little bit closer:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/757dd6285d554f4f52ae415fd39141a5

however, I still don't think it's possible to do what I want to do. The rationale is so that I can reuse the same Proxy object in the prototype, without having to create a new Proxy for each instance.

Comment: you've created a proxy for `v.foo` - why would it even know about `x`

Comment: it wouldn't know about x, but even if it was a proxy for v instead of v.foo - it wouldn't know about x either, unless it could somehow access the `this` value of the prototype method somehow

Comment: I am fumbling for a possible way to do this, but it might not be possible

Comment: You've created a proxy but then you're not using `p` anywhere?

Comment: yeah, I don't need to use p itself, I just need to use the hooks get/set

Comment: I got rid of the variable p, now it's just `new Proxy()` hopefully a little clearer; the gist is probably better example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some black magic here, but it works, you can use an Object.defineProperty getter to set the context for the proxied prototype method, (note this methodology will ***only work*** for synchronous parts of your code).

```
const proto = {};  // the prototype object 

const ctx = {
   val: null
};

const foo = function () {
    // the prototype method
    // do something with ctx.val which gets set dynamically
};

foo.bar = function(){
  // doing important stuff here
  // do something with ctx.val which gets set dynamically
};

const p = new Proxy(foo, {
  get: function (target, prop) {

    if (typeof prop === 'symbol') {
      return Reflect.get.apply(Reflect, arguments);
    }

    // do something with ctx.val
    // => ctx.val

  }
});


Object.defineProperty(proto, 'foo', {
  get: function() {
    ctx.val = this;  // set the context here!!
    return p;
  }
});
```

now we can use it like so:

```
proto.foo.bar()
```

when foo is accessed, it then dynamically sets the ctx for bar()

I end up using it like so:

```
const o = Object.create(proto);
o.foo.bar();
```

And we can also call `o.foo()` if we want to.

Comment: this answer is correct, but it's not simple, so read it carefully

Comment: This could fail in some cases then `a = proto.foo;somecode();a.bar();`

Comment: yes, it will fail if a.bar() and proto.foo was set to the wrong context.

Answer (score 2):

You're not looking for a proxy, all you need is a simple getter:

```
const v = {
  get foo() {
    console.log(this); // will log x
    return Object.assign(() => "hi", {bar: 42});
  }
};

const x = Object.create(v);

console.log(x.foo());
console.log(x.foo.bar);
```

---

> The rationale is so that I can reuse the same Proxy object in the prototype, without having to create a new Proxy for each instance.

For that you would need to use the proxy *as* the prototype. Your current code is just creating a proxy object and then throwing it away, which will not affect the original code in any way. You'd rather need to do something like

```
const p = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop) {
    console.log(target); // will log x
    if (prop == "foo")
      return Object.assign(() => "hi", {bar: 42});
  }
});

const x = Object.create(p);
//                      ^ use the proxy here!

console.log(x.foo());
console.log(x.foo.bar);
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, let me try it

Comment: I have pretty stupid/clever idea that will just take advantage of JS single-threaded nature - I can just set a context value when a property is accessed, that should work, will add an answer later. This is all synchronous code, nothing async, so I can some more black magic.

Comment: @AlexanderMills [What problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am simply trying to avoid creating a new Proxy for each instance. I have 1 prototype, and I want to use just 1 Proxy. That's the goal. If I use a Proxy per instance, I could have thousands and thousands of Proxy objects which hurts performance a lot.

Comment: OK, but that's rather standard usage not black magic :-) Still, why are you using proxies at all?

Comment: my use case is totally out there...I will add an answer explaining how I solved it

Comment: just added it, it works - the Proxy is still useful, but not as imperative as it was before.

Comment: I am proxy-ing the assert library ... instead of defining a 100 methods, I can use 1 Proxy...hard to explain

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the proxy to the object prototype.

```js
SomeObject.prototype = new Proxy(
    SomeObject.prototype,
    SomeObjectHandlerProxy
);

instance = new SomeObject();
```

something like should work

Comment: Note that for built-in objects `prototype` is not writable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76366833/10406353