# How to proxy Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I tried to proxy `Function.prototype`.

I created a new `Proxy` and rewrote the `toString` method, however `console.log('cas')` doesn't work, why?

```js
Function.prototype = new Proxy(Function.prototype, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {},
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
    console.log('cas')
  }
})
Function.prototype._toString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log('bb')
  return this._toString()
}
```

Comment: Placing a Proxy on the Function prototype, don't think that's going to end well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, we cannot overwrite `Function.prototype` but we can set the prototype of `Function.prototype` (an evil professor's laugh here):

```js
const props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Function.prototype);

const masked = {};

for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
    Object.defineProperty(masked, name, value);
}

const prototype = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, property, receiver) {
        // avoid recursion and stack overflow
        if(!['call', 'apply'].includes(property)){
          console.log(`getting ${property}`);
        }
        return masked[property];
    },
    set: function (target, property, value, receiver) {
        console.log(`setting ${property}`);
        masked[property] = value;
    }
});

// clear Function.prototype and assign our proxy prototype to it

for (const k in props) {
    delete Function.prototype[k];
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Function.prototype, prototype);

Function.prototype._toString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function () {
    console.log("I'm new toString()");
    return this._toString();
};

const test = () => false;

console.log(test.toString());
```

---

**UPDATE**
The author noticed that the solution doesn't work in node.js.
The reason that `console.log` is environment specific plus overriding `Function.prototype` means that if you call a function that calls `apply`, `call`, `bind` you go into recursion and stack overflow (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded).
So the code should be adjusted to your specific execution environment. On my node.js version 18 these tweaks helped. Moreover I had to override `console.log` since the output was empty. Again, environment-specific (seems another investigation...). During debugging `console.log` worked but required to avoid getting `listener` property.
So my conclusion: it works if you care about recursion with specific methods on your platform AND I will be working on an environment-independent solution, the plan is to register function calls and avoid recursion by checking whether there's already a function call that leads to the stack overflow.

```js
const props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Function.prototype);

const masked = {};

for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
    Object.defineProperty(masked, name, value);
}

const log = msg => process.stdout.write(msg + '\n');

const prototype = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, property, receiver) {
        // avoid recursion and stack overflow
        if (!['call', 'apply', 'bind'].includes(property)) {
            log(`getting ${property}`);
        }
        return masked[property];
    },
    set: function (target, property, value, receiver) {
        log(`setting ${property}`);
        masked[property] = value;
    }
});

// clear Function.prototype and assign our proxy prototype to it

for (const k in props) {
    delete Function.prototype[k];
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Function.prototype, prototype);

Function.prototype._toString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function () {
    log('I\'m new toString()');
    return this._toString();
};

const test = () => false;

log(test.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: The code is work in chrome,it is a very good idea. However, in nodejs, the code raise an error . The version of nodejs is 18.12.1
node:tty:85
  if (!(this instanceof WriteStream))       
             ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @yglin updated the answer, pls check it. also i'll be working on a universal solution. by the way if you find my idea very good i'd ask you to upvote my answer (the arrow up), i've put a lot of effort into it. also if you find my answer working for you you could consider to accept my answer as the resolution (the checkbox). thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I created a new `Proxy` and rewrote the `toString` method, however `console.log('cas')` doesn't work, why?

The answer is simple: `Function.prototype` is not writable.

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Function, 'prototype'));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

As for why JS didn't throw an error... It's JS. What do you expect?

On the other hand, you can use [`'use strict'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851) to make these kinds of error explicit (thanks @Keith).

To prevent `Function#toString()` from being overwritten, you can re-define it:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'toString', {
  value: Function.prototype.toString,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false
});
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function f() {}

console.log(f.toString()); // function f() {}

Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'toString', {
  value: Function.prototype.toString,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false
});

Function.prototype._toString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log('overwritten');
  return Function.prototype._toString.call(this);
}

console.log(Object.hasOwn(Function.prototype, '_toString')); // true
console.log(Object.hasOwn(Function.prototype, 'toString')); // Also true
console.log(f.toString()); // function f() {}, not tainted.
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Didn't throw an error, maybe because didn't use `'use strict';`

Comment: Is there any method to watch the rewrite of Function.prototype.toString?

Comment: @yglin That means you just want to prevent `Function#toString()` from being overwritten? That is called an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @InSync I'm curious why it can't be proxied. When this question had been solved, I  want to know how to prevent Function#toString() from being overwritten

Comment: Maybe I should create another question?

Comment: @yglin I updated my answer. Check to see if it works for you.

Comment: @InSync posted another answer, looks awesome

Comment: @yglin please check my final solution